# How to resolve Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): cyclic object value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This block of code:

```
      const data = {
        user_id: userID,
        comment: comment
      };
      const url = `http://localhost:5000/blog/comments${category}/${slug}`;
      const headers = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" };
      axios.post(url, data, headers).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.data.message);
      });
    }
```

is giving me this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): cyclic object value
```

from what I've gathered so far "cyclic object value" refers to javascript objects that at some point refer to itself hence throws an error. From the code above it's not very obvious how I accomplished such error.

I would appreciated any pointers here.

**Attempt to provide a minimal example:**

Post.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AddComment from "./AddComment";
import axios from "axios";

const Post = props => {
const { userID, trace, setTrace, isAuthenticated } = useGlobalContext();
const [obj, setObj] = useState([]);
const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
const [showLoginWarning, setShowLoginWarning] = useState(false);
const { firstColumn, secondColumn, slug, category } = props;

const handleComment = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      setShowLoginWarning(true);
    } else {
      const data = {
        user_id: userID,
        comment: comment
      };
      const url = `http://localhost:5000/blog/comments${category}/${slug}`;
      const headers = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" };
      axios
        .post(url, data, headers)
        .then(resp => {
          console.log(resp.data.message);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTrace(category + `/${slug}`);
    //console.log(trace);
    let obj = firstColumn.filter(post => post.slug === slug);
    if (obj.length === 0) {
      obj = secondColumn.filter(post => post.slug === slug);
    }
    setObj(obj);
    const headers = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" };
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/blog/comments${trace}/${slug}`;
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(resp => {
        setComments(resp.data.message);
        console.log(resp.data.message);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowLoginWarning(false);
    }, 7000);
  }, [showLoginWarning]);
  const img_file = `http://localhost:5000/blog/fetch_image/post/${slug}`;

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "40px" }} className="container">
      <div className="columns">
        <div className="column is-four-fifths">
          <div className="content">
            {obj.map(prop => (
              <div key={prop.id}>
                <h4 className="title is-4">
                  <img src={img_file} alt={prop.title} />
                  <br />
                  {prop.title}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <small>{prop.timestamp}</small>
                </h4>

                <br />
                <p>{prop.post}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column">
          <br />
          <Link to={category} className="button is-link" id="backbtn">
            Back
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <section className="section">
        <h1 className="title">Section</h1>
        <h2 className="subtitle">
          A simple container to divide your page into <strong>sections</strong>,
          like the one you're currently reading.
        </h2>
        <AddComment
          onComment={handleComment}
          showLoginWarning={showLoginWarning}
          onChange={setComment}
        />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

AddComment.jsx:

```
import React from "react";

const AddComment = props => {
  const { showLoginWarning, onComment, onChange } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {showLoginWarning && (
        <div className="notification is-warning">
          <strong>You need to be logged in to comment.</strong>
        </div>
      )}
      <section id="textareaSection" className="section">
        <form onSubmit={onComment}>
          <div className="field">
            <div className="control">
              <textarea
                className="textarea"
                cols="2"
                rows="2"
                placeholder="What's On Your Mind ?"
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                style={{ float: "right", marginTop: "1em" }}
                className="button is-link"
              >
                Post
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddComment;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./assets/bulma/css/bulma.css";
import "./assets/stylesheet.css";
import Post from "./Post";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { AppProvider } from "./context";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <Post />
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Hi MArk, could you post a [minimum reproducable example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so far. The code you've provided doesn't produce an error as it isn't executable.

your `userID` variable is of particular interest.

Comment: @James So sorry for resplying so late. I've added minimal example without backend as in this case backend code isn't important.